# Ps4 bad graphic (anti aliasing) or its the Tv?

Tags: ps4

Hi guy so i played many games on ps4 in samsung lcd Tv (Full HD 1080p), many games almos every game has a bad graphic anti aliasing (i mean the edges of everything it's like pixeli when im moving but when im not moving its not that obvious) games like bloodborne or Divison or The Crew (the crew was actually awful)

my question is that is everyone have this problems or just me ?

is this a console problem or maybe the Tv is old ?

[image: if you focus to the part is colored in the picture on the video]

Video :   https://ufile.io/da045

it seems ok in the pictures but if you see the video it is soooooo bad i mean really like ps3

Comment: If you're looking for the pixels, you'll find them. "Bad Graphics" isn't much to go by to find a solution. - Is the PS4 set to display on 1080p? What's the type of cable you're using to connect the two? Is there anything between the TV and the PS4 like a HDMI swticher?

Comment: thanks for reply.no there is nothing in between and yes i set it on 1080p. i'll upload a video for you to see my problem please wait

Comment: Aliasing is normal in games, even on PC. This is especially true on consoles, where developers choose to not bother about aliasing in favor of more detailed landscapes and whatnot. Your TV is most definitely not to blame.

Comment: Would you be able to upload the video to YouTube or a steaming site?  The provided link requires a sign-on to download. - Besides that, There's some LoD (Level of Detail) + Motion blur going on, but that's more in part with how the game was made.  Any other examples?

Comment: so there is nothing wrong with the console or Tv ? @NBN-Alex

Comment: That is called [Motion-Blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_blur "Motion-Blur"), if that is what you're talking about..
it is hard to tell what you're pointing at on the graphic.

Comment: +1 for the effort put into the question. That video looks completely fine.

Comment: @DCShannon Are you serious ? The game look so bad

Comment: @BrandonYopp you can't notice it in the image you must see the video (link is under image) in the video you shod notice the bad graphic in that area that i showed

Comment: I think it's gotta be the motion blur, because all the graphics look fine. I played The Crew a bit when it was free on Xbox Live, and there was definitely a lot of motion blur. I was actually really impressed with that game's graphics. Best part.

Comment: Maybe the reaction time of the TV simply isn't good enough. They're usually worse than monitors for gaming purpose. Try a monitor instead and see if your problem persists.